# How come I always get back Memcached::RES_NO_SERVERS when I try to set a value with Memcached?

Tags: php, memcached

```
$ sudo service memcached start
Starting memcached: memcached.

$ php-shell.sh 
PHP-Shell - Version 0.3.1, with readline() support
(c) 2006, Jan Kneschke <jan@kneschke.de>

>> use '?' to open the inline help 

>> $mc = new Memcached('start')
Memcached::__set_state(array(
))
>> $mc->set('x','y')
false
>> $mc->getResultCode()
20
>> Memcached::RES_NO_SERVERS
20
```

I've started memcached, so presumably a server is running, no? Do I need to do something anything else so it can find the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect to the server first...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.addserver.php

```
Memcached::addServer('localhost', 11211);
```

Comment: Beautiful. Works now. Thank you muchly!